# gstreamer rtsp client connection refused error

Tags: linux, gstreamer, gst-launch

I have installed Gstreamer on my i.MX6 board. I want to stream the camera connected using RTSP.

The following command displays the camera content on the LVDS screen:

```
gst-launch tvsrc ! Imxv4vl2sink
```

Instead of displaying it on the screen, I want to send the content over network RTSP and display it on other device's display

I used the following command to start streaming which works without throwing any error

```
gst-launch-0.10 -vv imxv4l2src ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=30/1, width=1024
, height=768 ! vpuenc codec=avc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5004
sync=false
```

On the other device, I executed the following command:

```
gst-launch rtspsrc location=rtsp://<ip Address>:5004 name=source ! queue ! rtph264depay !
vpudec low-latency=true ! imxv4l2sink
```

It fails with the following error:

```
gstrtspsrc.c(5685): gst_rtspsrc_retrieve_sdp (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:source:
Failed to connect. (System error: Connection refused)
```

I can ping from the other device to the streaming device.

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending RTP over UDP, but do not provide any RTSP protocol. So your receiver which tries to connect via RTSP will fail. You either need to use the `GstRTSPServer` class and implement some logic as an application on the sender side or receive your data via `udpsrc`. For the latter you still need a way to transmit SDP data (which usually is one thing an RTSP server does).

Comment: gst-launch udpsrc port=5004 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! vpudec low-latency=true ! imxv4l2sink sync=false

Comment: Yes, you are right.. I used udpsrc and it worked... Thanks.